# How to get Alert object with PhantomJSDriver in java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, phantomjs, alert

I'm trying PhantomJSDriver for testing application and I got errors to get Selenium equivalent of Alert object. I've tried this :

```
if (driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
    PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
    Alert alert = (Alert) phantom.executeScript("return window.alert;");
} 
else {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
}
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I get Alert object ?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting???

Comment: I must change the cast in String (ClassCastException) and after I get this String: "function alert() { [native code] }". It's normal because I get the javascript alert function.

Comment: You can just simply accept alert by this ... `phantom.executeScript("window.alert = function(){return true;}");`..No need to cast it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using `PhantomJS` you can get the `Alert` object.

To simply **accept** `alerts`,  you should try as below for every time page reloaded that would have an alert later on page.

```
if (driver instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
PhantomJSDriver phantom = (PhantomJSDriver) driver;
phantom.executeScript("window.alert = function(){return true;}");
}
```

Hope it will help you...:)